# How to set column header in VBA Userform ListBox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with displaying column headers in a ListBox in my userform. Everything is working fine but could not show the headers.

My problem is described here:

**1.** Actual data:

[image]

**2.** VBA code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim MyArray1
Set ws1 = Sheets("Accounts")
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A5:E" & ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
With Me.ListBox10
        .BorderStyle = 1
        .BorderColor = &H80000012
        .BackColor = &H80FFFF
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = rng1.Columns.Count
     MyArray1 = rng1
    .List = MyArray1
    .ColumnWidths = "40,70,60,60,50"
  End With
End Sub
```

**3.** Output result:

[image]

Can you please guide me how to set Column Header to ListBox? And format it (column headers)?

Column headers are `Sheets("Accounts").Range("A5:E5")`

Comment: What about changing this part `.ColumnHeads =False`?

Comment: This (**.ColumnHeads =False**) just removes the original Header Line. Which is empty. It is not a proper solution.

Comment: Why not just hide the column headers altogether and place labels at the top of the control, then alter the label captions? You would then also have options for formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to the below.  Note that it's using `RowSource` and the range is starting at `A6` rather than `A5`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    'Dim MyArray1
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Accounts")
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A6:E" & ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    With Me.ListBox10
            .BorderStyle = 1
            .BorderColor = &H80000012
            .BackColor = &H80FFFF
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = rng1.Columns.Count
        .RowSource = rng1.Address(External:=True)
         'MyArray1 = rng1
        '.List = MyArray1
        .ColumnWidths = "40,70,60,60,50"
      End With
End Sub
```

https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-listbox/

> Column Headers are another confusing element of the ListBox. If you
> use the RowSource property to add data to the ListBox then the line
> above the Range will be automatically used as the header.   .   .   If
> you use the List or AddItem property to fill the ListBox then the
> column headers are not available. The best solution, albeit a
> frustrating one, is to use labels above the ListBox. I know it sounds
> crazy but that unfortunately is the reality. The one advantage is that
> you can use the Label click event which is useful if you plan to sort
> the data by a column.

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you try loading a list Box **otherwise then using its `RowSource`** it starts loading from the row before the header, **even if you set `ColumnHeads = True`**. To be more strange, even using `RowSource`, **it shows headers only if the respective range starts one row below the header you need**. So, your code should become:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range

 Set ws1 = Sheets("Accounts")
 Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A5:E" & ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
 With Me.ListBox1
        .BorderStyle = 1
        .BorderColor = &H80000012
        .BackColor = &H80FFFF
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = rng1.Columns.count
    .ColumnWidths = "40,70,60,60,50"
    .RowSource = rng1.Parent.name & "!" & rng1.Resize(rng1.rows.count - 1).Offset(1).address
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @FaneDuru, good to se you again. you solved my problems many time. You are my favourite. I got two currect answer. And it is hard to deside which one I should choose as answered. StackOverFlow doesn't allow choose both answer as Correct. But **Mr. DarrenBartrupCook** answered first. So I choose that answer as Answered. Hope you will never mind.

Comment: @Prabhat Vishwas You did it as it should! I started answering and planned a more complete approach. I had to stop for wolving some emergency staff and posted after that only my first attempt. I did not refresh the sheet and did not see the other answer. I had something able to also work in case of loading the list box from an array...